# Windows 2003 Server Losing Time

Tags: windows-server-2003, time

I'm running an e-commerce site on a Windows 2003 Server 32-bit (written in .NET, connecting to another W2k3 64-bit Server running SQL server.)

It's imperative that the two servers always stay exactly in time with one another, and so they are both set to synchronize with Windows Time Server.

Lately though, the web server is falling behind by 6-10 seconds every 24 hours.

I'm not sure if it's of any significance but it seems this started a few weeks after our latest deployment, a Windows Service that handles a number of TCP/IP connections to other servers. It's all written in .NET so nothing too low-level, and it doesn't mess with the time...but it does seem like a coincidence.

Any other ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you updated any drivers on this server lately?

Comment: @GregD, not that I'm aware of. There were some automatic updates about a week ago though.

Comment: Are either of the servers virtual?

Comment: Nope, both installed on physical Dell rack-mounted servers

Comment: CMOS battery is running flat on the machine?

Answer (score 1):

How about having one server sync with your external time source and the other server sync with this server?

Comment: That still doesn't solve the root problem, which is that this sophisticated server can't keep up with a $5 wristwatch. :)

Comment: Ah, if only Timex made servers... ;)

Comment: Remember the Timex commercial where they attached a watch to a whale, I think at the old Marineland of the Pacific?  I want to see someone do that with a server ...

Comment: I remember loading a piece of software on my 486DX that allowed me to sync my watch by flashing black and white bars on the screen and holding my watch up to it.